# Caesar's cipher in VC#

Tags: c#, cryptography

```
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    char name[50];
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter the name:>");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    j=strlen(name);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{
    name[i] = name[i]+3;
}
    printf("ENCRYTED NAME=>%s",name);
}
```

This a caesar's cipher in c programming 
friends i want use this same thing in VC# 
where i will get input from user through textbox.
please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps you could start with a C# console application that does the same thing as the above C code. Once you've got that working, then hook up that code to textbox. Work on one thing at a time, and the whole process will seem less bewildering.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a console application, you can do this:

```
Console.Write("Enter the name:>");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
```